# Sum values in JSON response with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops, dynamic, sum

I am trying to sum up a col1, col2, and col3 in my JSON using Jquery and not sure how to go about doing it using the .each loop. Another problem is col1, and col2, and col3 are dynamic so the names will be changing.

This is my JSON string:

```
 var data = [
{
    "Country": "Spain",
    "Year": "2012",
    "col1": "100.75",
    "col2": "500",
    "col3": "200"
},
{
    "Country": "Spain",
    "Year": "2013",
    "col1": "200",
    "col2": "500",
    "col3": "300"
},
{
    "Country": "France",
    "Year": "2011",
    "col1": "100",
    "col2": "100",
    "col3": "300"
},
{
    "Country": "France",
    "Year": "2012",
    "col1": "100",
    "col2": "100",
    "col3": "300"
},
{
    "Country": "France",
    "Year": "2013",
    "col1": "100",
    "col2": "200",
    "col3": "300"
}
]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RHLKa/

I want two results that would look something like this:

1) Totals per country

```
Spain 300.75, 1000, 500
France 300, 400, 900
```

2) Grand total:

```
["col1", 600.75],
["col2", 1400],
["col3", 1400]
```

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store results it's better to use object (or associative array). Also not to mix properties that should be applied and that should not - you may store them in a separate array, which could be a property in a config file or smth like that. Here is the code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwRSr/)):

```
var countries = {},
    columns = {},
    sumCols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];

$.each(data, function(index, obj) {
    if (!countries[obj['Country']]) {
        countries[obj['Country']] = {};
    }
    $.each(sumCols, function (index, col) {
        if (!countries[obj['Country']][col]) {
            countries[obj['Country']][col] = 0;
        }
        if (!columns[col]) {
            columns[col] = 0;
        }
        var val = parseFloat(obj[col]);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            countries[obj['Country']][col] += val;
            columns[col] += val;
        }
    });
});
```

As the result:

```
{
    "Spain":{
        "col1":300.75,
        "col2":1000,
        "col3":500},
    "France":{
        "col1":300,
        "col2":400,
        "col3":900
    }
}

{
    "col1":600.75,
    "col2":1400,
    "col3":1400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you're going to face working with dynamic property names is the fact that JavaScript explicitly does not guarantee ordering. So you can't really match up looping over object property names with an array index. Because of that, you would need to use objects to store your results. Here's a (not very optimized) bit of code that should work. You can manipulate the results afterwards if need be.

```
var results = {};
var totals = {};

// Loop over the array of data
for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
    var o = data[d];
    var country = o["Country"];
    var values = results[country] || {};
    // Since the column names may change, we need to loop over the object
    for (var key in o) {
        // Weed out the two known keys
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.toLowerCase() != "country" && key.toLowerCase() != "year") {
            // Now find the entry in the values obj that matches
            var column = values[key] || 0;
            // And the corresponding entry in the totals object
            var totalsColumn = totals[key] || 0;
            column += parseFloat(o[key]);
            totalsColumn += parseFloat(o[key]);
            values[key] = column;
            totals[key] = totalsColumn;
        }
    }
    results[country] = values;
}
```

This yields two objects, `results`, which looks like this:

```
France:
    col1: 300
    col2: 400
    col3: 900
Spain:
    col1: 300.75
    col2: 1000
    col3: 500
```

And `totals`, which looks like this:

```
col1: 600.75
col2: 1400
col3: 1400
```

I posted this into an updated version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHLKa/1/).

Comment: @ken.dunnigton thanks for this piece of code.The total needs to be in array with this format as I am passing this into highcharts, how can I get it like this
    var total = [["col1", 600,75], ["col2",1400], ["col3",1400]]